# Basic Django about using list

Tags: django

I am new with Django, started learning. I am trying to access a list in for loop, but I can't

```
todo_list = ({'count':'one','count':'two','count':'three'})
raw_template="""   {% for todo in todo_list.count  %}
    <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item }} </p>   {% endfor %}   """
t =  Template(raw_template)
c = Context({'todo_list':todo_list})
t.render(c)
u'\n  \n    <p>1:  </p>\n  \n    <p>2:  </p>\n  \n <p>3:  </p>\n  \n  '
```

Please let me know where I am making the mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: This is basic Python, not Django. A dict can't have more than one of each key.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a list in the context:

```
todo_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
  <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ todo }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

All the code together:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

t = Template("""
{% for todo in todo_list %}
<p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ todo }}</p>
{% endfor %}
""")
c = Context({
    'todo_list': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
})
t.render(c)
```

Comment: I used as follows:

    todo_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    raw_template="""
      {% for todo in todo_list %}
        <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item }} </p>
      {% endfor %}
      """
    t =  Template(raw_template)
    c = Context ({'todo_list':todo_list})
    t.render(Context(c))

But the Output is same:

u'\n  \n    <p>1:  </p>\n  \n    <p>2:  </p>\n  \n    <p>3:  </p>\n  \n

Comment: Ahh! A silly mistake I was making. :(
Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You need `{{ todo }}` in the for loop instead of `{{ item }}`